# How do I remove all lines matching a pattern from a set of files?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I've got an irritating closed-source tool which writes specific information into its configuration file. If you then try to use the configuration on a different file, then it loads the old file. Grrr...

Luckily, the configuration files are text, so I can version control them, and it turns out that if one just removes the offending line from the file, no harm is done.

But the tool keeps putting the lines back in. So every time I want to check in new versions of the config files, I have to remove all lines containing the symbol `openDirFile`.

I'm about to construct some sort of bash command to run grep -v on each file, store the result in a temporary file, and then delete the original and rename the temporary, but I wondered if anyone knew of a nice clean solution, or had already concocted and debugged a similar invocation.

For extra credit, how can this be done without destroying a symbolic link in the same directory (favourite.rc->signals.rc)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sed -i '/openDirFile/d' *.conf
```

this do the removing on all conf files

you can also combine the line with "find" command if your conf files are located in different paths.

Note that -i will do the removing "in place".

Comment: In case you came here from a duplicate, note that you cannot use single quotes if your search pattern is in a shell variable; use double quotes around your `sed` script in that case (and obviously adapt if required, i.e. double any literal backslashes, escape any literal dollar signs, etc). `sed -i "/$variable/d" *.conf`

Comment: The `-i` option is non-standard but rather widely available. However, some platforms (including *BSD / MacOS) require you to specify an argument to `-i`, so `sed -i '' 's/openDirFile/d' *.conf`

Answer (score 0):

This was the bash-spell that I came up with:

```
for i in *.rc ; do
    TMP=$(mktemp)
    grep -v openDirFile "$i" >"$TMP" && mv "$TMP" "$i"
done
```

(You can obviously turn this into a one-liner by replacing the newlines with semicolons, except after `do`.)

Kent's answer is clearly superior.